# ActiveX Checkbox calls Sub to loop through all Bookmarks and perform conditional action (to specific group)

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-word, activex, bookmarks

I'm using VBA in Word to create a SmartForm where the user can tick a checkbox in order to display certain information which I have Bookmarked using the naming format "TEXT_BUTANE"

Because each product (BUTANE/ PROPANE/ ETHANE) will have multiple Bookmarks throughout the document I'm naming them "TEXT_BUTANE1" "TEXT_BUTANE2" etc

So I'd then like to loop through all Bookmarks and hide/show sections in the document depending on which group it belongs to i.e all Bookmarks starting with "TEXT_BUT" would be considered a group that would be collectively hidden (or shown if checked)

I'm getting a compile error "Next without For" but from what I can see the syntax is correct

It was working before creating the LoopThroughBookmarks Sub, but I need something like this so I can hide/show multiple sections of the document

Any help would be much appreciated

```
Private Sub CHECK_BUTANE_Click()

Dim vw As Word.View
Dim bChecked As Boolean
Dim bkm As Word.Bookmark

'turned on non-printing characters individually so that
'not displaying Hidden text does not affect these settings.
Set vw = Application.ActiveWindow.View
If vw.ShowAll = True Then     'if TRUE then SHOW following
    vw.ShowParagraphs = True
    vw.ShowObjectAnchors = True
    vw.ShowTabs = True
    vw.ShowHyphens = True
    vw.ShowOptionalBreaks = True
    vw.ShowSpaces = True
End If
vw.ShowAll = False            'if FALSE then HIDE following
vw.ShowHiddenText = False
bChecked = Me.CHECK_BUTANE.Value
                              'if CHECKED
If bChecked Then
    Call LoopThroughBookmarks("BUT", True) 'then TRUE so loop through bookmarks passing PRODUCT
Else
    Call LoopThroughBookmarks("BUT", False) 'then FALSE so loop through bookmarks passing PRODUCT
End If
End Sub


Public Sub LoopThroughBookmarks(product As String, bChecked As Boolean)

Dim bkm As Bookmark
Dim strMarks() As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim checkString As String
Dim bkmName As String


checkString = "CHECK_" + product     'CHECK_BUT or CHECK_PRO or CHECK_MET

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
    ReDim strMarks(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count - 1)
    intCount = 0
    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks         'Set bkm to be current Bookmark
        bkmName = Left$(bkm.Name, 9)                 'taking first 9 chars for bkm comparison
        If bkmName = checkString Then                'if TRUE
            bkm.Range.Font.Hidden = Not bChecked        'then hidden is false
        Else                                         'is FALSE
            bkm.Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked         'so stay visibility
    Next bkm
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Cindy Meister I really appreciated your previous answer that got me started on this! Now I'm just wondering if you're able to help with this revision to show/hide multiple sections? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting that error because you are missing an `End If` immediately before the `Next` in this part of your code:

```
    If bkmName = checkString Then                'if TRUE
        bkm.Range.Font.Hidden = Not bChecked        'then hidden is false
    Else                                         'is FALSE
        bkm.Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked         'so stay visibility
Next bkm
```

As a further observation, you could probably simplify this part of your code

```
bChecked = Me.CHECK_BUTANE.Value
                              'if CHECKED
If bChecked Then
    Call LoopThroughBookmarks("BUT", True) 'then TRUE so loop through bookmarks passing PRODUCT
Else
    Call LoopThroughBookmarks("BUT", False) 'then FALSE so loop through bookmarks passing PRODUCT
```

to

```
Call LoopThroughBookmarks("BUT",Me.CHECK_BUTANE.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you! That syntax wasn't included in the example I was following.. so thanks for the clarification :)  

Unfortunately the simplification you suggested doesn't work in my code, I've tried it a few which ways (either passing bChecked, or Me.CHECK_BUTANE.Value) but neither allow the program to compile

Comment: Just reading your comment I wondered if you'd just done the "simplification" (the second bit) and not added the missing End If (the first bit) ?

Comment: FWIW when I added the End If line here, the compilation error disappeared.